# How can I get notified about security updates to JFrog Artifactory Pro?

Tags: artifactory

We are trying to stay on top of version updates in today's security climate. How can I get notified about security updates or releases of Artifactory Pro?

Answer (score 4):

You can view the CVE's that were discovered to impact Artifactory and were fixed in [Fixed Security Vulnerabilities](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Fixed+Security+Vulnerabilities)

Answer (score 4):

Usually, once JFrog releases a security patch to Artifactory an email is sent to all license owners. If you haven't received such emails, you should contact your Account Manager at JFrog.

Regardless, if you wish to be notified with any JFrog Artifactory release you should follow the relevant repository in Bintray, for example: [jfrog-artifactory-pro-rpm](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-pro-rpms/jfrog-artifactory-pro-rpm).